# Does there exist a simple locality-preserving mapping from the unit interval to the surface of a sphere?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, spheres

The 1D unit inverval $[0,1)$ can be mapped to the 2D unit square $\left[0, 1\right)^2$ in a way that preserves locality via the Hilbert Curve.

Is there any similarly simple locality-preserving mapping from the 1D unit interval to the 2D surface of a sphere $\{(x,y,z) | x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\}$?

It would be great if $0$ and $1$ mapped to the exact same point on the sphere under this mapping (as opposed to e.g. being mapped to opposite ends of the sphere).

P.S.: I am a dilettante in this area, so I have no idea which tags or areas are appropriate for this post. If someone could help editing in relevant tags, it would be great.

Comment: Note that via the (Riemannian) exponential map there is a continuous map $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow S^2$ such that its restriction to eg $B(0,1)$ is surjective. So you can map continuously $[0,1)$ into some large “rectangle” of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and compose.

Comment: What do you mean by "locality-preserving mapping...to". The Hilbert and Peano curves are continuous surjections, but not bijections. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @almagest Like it says in the first application on the wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve#Applications_and_mapping_algorithms), I take "preserving locality" to mean that "points close together in 1D space will be mapped to points close together in the 2D space". There's probably a more rigorous epsilon-delta definition out there.

Comment: Yes, that would be a continuous surjection. But note that multiple points map to any given point of the target (with a few exceptions maybe).There are no homeomorphisms, unsurprisingly.